# Unity: Keep desktop file information for detached process

Tags: ubuntu-unity

I have the following desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Game
Exec=/usr/games/mygame %U
Icon=mygame
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Game;

Comment=Start my game
Comment[de_DE]=Starte mein Spiel
```

and the entry is shown perfectly in *Ubuntu (13.04) Unity Dash*.

When `mygame` is executed, it spawns a detached process again and I get a *Unity Launcher* entry with a question mark and `Untitled window`.

Is there a way to tell Unity, where the (detached) process originated or which desktop file to assign to the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround was to set the X11 property [`_NET_WM_ICON`](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html) on the detached process.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the absolute path for your Icon file. This might help otherwise it could be a bug in the bamf.

Comment: Thanks. Reading up on _bamf_ led me to realize the problem with launching detached processes (see edit).

Comment: You have to work on the file itself now there is no possibility for a workaround with the ".desktop" file. You have to remove the abstraction of the symbolic link or use the executable directly.

Comment: That's not an option, since we have an update mechanism, which might even replace the underlying files. So we need one point, which decides what to start.